# SSRS passing date parameter not returning any result

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
'CPT_Code' = CPT.CPT_Code
,'CPT_Short_Description' = CPT.CPT_Short_Desc
,'CPT_Code_Description' = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CPT.CPT_CODE) + ' - ' + CPT.CPT_Short_Desc
FROM dbo.FACT_ProCharge AS FACT WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.DIM_Treatment CPT WITH (NOLOCK) ON FACT.TreatmentKey = CPT.TreatmentKey
INNER JOIN dbo.DIM_Date SERVDATE WITH (NOLOCK) ON FACT.ServiceDateKey = SERVDATE.DateKey
WHERE FACT.BillServiceAreaKey = (SELECT MIN(BillServiceAreaKey) FROM dbo.DIM_BillServiceArea WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE SERV_AREA_ID = '14')
AND SERVDATE.SQL_Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND CPT.CPT_Level_1_Name <> 'Evaluation and Management Services'    --No E&M
AND CPT.CPT_CODE <> '99024'                                         --No post-op visit
AND CPT.CPT_CODE  NOT BETWEEN '80000' AND '89999'                   --No Lab codes
ORDER BY CPT_Code
```

It will not return any results after I passing a datetime parameter to @StartDate and @EndDate. 
If I comment out the INNER JOIN DIM_Date and date range in where clause, it will return the cpt_codes I want.

The query runs fine in Management studio with desire outputs.

Any thoughts of what should I do?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Parameters tab of your Dataset properties?

Answer (score 0):

Hie i am kind of newbie but i just tried to resolve your issue .try this if it helps you i will be very happy

SERVDATE.SQL_Date >= @StartDate AND SERVDATE.SQL_Date <= @EndDate

Thanks